# Why is HttpClient.execute returning null?

Tags: java, httpclient, httpcontext, cisco

Below is my code snippet:

```
private HttpClient httpClient;
private CookieStore APICookieStore;
private HttpHost targetHost;
private AuthCache authCache;
private CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;

httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
nxAPICookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
targetHost = new HttpHost(swtch.getHostIP(), 80, "http");
authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
authCache.put(targetHost, new BasicScheme());
credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(swtch.getUserName(), swtch.getPassword()));
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/ins");
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
context.setAuthCache(authCache);
context.setCookieStore(APICookieStore);
// JSON command that needs to be sent across
StringEntity postBody = new StringEntity(parsedString,"UTF-8");
post.setEntity(postBody);
// Execute send and receive to remote switch
JsonNode returnNode = httpClient.execute(targetHost, post, this, context);
```

`parsedString`:

```
{ "ins_api" : { "version" : "1.0", "type": "cli_conf", "chunk": "0", "sid": "1", "input": "show clock", "output_format": "json" } }
```

I am not sure what is missing here; all the data seems correct, but the value of  `returnNode` is: `null`.

Comment: Within `parsedString`, what are the intended types of the `chunk` and `sid` properties? They have been defined as `string` values (because they are within double-quotes), but look as though either of them (or both) are intended to be numeric. If that is the case, remove the double-quotes - numeric property values are represented without quotes in `JSON`. The same rule also applies for the value: `null`.

Comment: problem was,I hadnt override handleResponse(),after implementing ResponseHandler<JsonNode>,working now